# Firebase Admin NoClassDefFoundError: FirebaseOptions$Builder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using this:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount;
    try {
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("firebase_key.json");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Reached here!");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://*.firebaseio.com/")
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

However, the application crashes with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for FirebaseOptions$Builder`

My `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.1.1'
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ.

Logcat:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions$Builder
10:57:43 AM web.1 |     at com.x.*.TokenGenerator.main(TokenGenerator.java:26)
10:57:43 AM web.1 |  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder
10:57:43 AM web.1 |     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
10:57:43 AM web.1 |     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
10:57:43 AM web.1 |     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
10:57:43 AM web.1 |     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I have my firebase_key.json in the root of the app.

What's causing this?

Comment: add your logcat

Comment: Didn't think it's needed. Added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I was using this command to build:

```
gradlew clean install
```

However, the Jar generated by that doesn't contain the **dependencies**. And the Firebase Admin SDK is a dependency.

So what I did is I used [shadowJar](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow), which generates a Jar that contains dependencies. Unlike `gradlew clean install`.

Then, in the Procfile, I set it to the Jar that shadowJar generates. The only problem I see to have is, now I have to go to IntelliJ and run the shadowJar from there, since there doesn't seem any command to run it from the commandline.

Hope this helps

Comment: I know this is somewhat old, but does it mean we need to use a third party library to use Firebase Admin SDK in java? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the right import on the gradle for firebase options, there's no need for admin package, you need the core :

Instead of `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.1.1'`

Use `compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1"`